# Fix the "-e" is deprecated warning with gnome-terminal

Tags: linux, shell, unix, gnome-terminal

I have the below script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run abc-app services
cd abc-app/packages/auth-service

tab=" --tab"
options_1=()
options_2=()

cmd_1[1]="yarn start"
cmd_1[2]="cd ../../api/shipper; yarn start:shipper"
cmd_1[3]="cd ../../frontend/shipper; yarn dev"

cmd_2[1]="yarn start:procure-app"
cmd_2[2]="yarn start:procure-worker"
cmd_2[3]="yarn start:mail-worker"
cmd_2[4]="yarn start:transporter"
cmd_2[5]="cd ../frontend/shipper; yarn dev"
cmd_2[6]="cd ../frontend/transporter; yarn dev"


for i in 1 2 3; do
options_1+=($tab -e "bash -c '${cmd_1[i]} ; bash'" )
done

for j in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
options_2+=($tab -e "bash -c '${cmd_2[j]} ; bash'" )
done

gnome-terminal "${options_1[@]}"

cd
cd Documents/Code/abc-procure

gnome-terminal "${options_2[@]}"
```

When I run the script using `./startServices.sh`, its runs as expected but with the below warnings

```
# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
```

I see that's just a syntax change I need to do, but not sure how to apply and make it work.

Comment: The warning message says how to rewrite it. What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: This isn't really about Bash, so it might be better to ask on [unix.se].

Comment: Do note [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) -- putting commands in variables is a bad idea in general (they should be stored in functions instead! -- yes, you can pass a function on a program's command line; that can look like `bash -c "$(declare -f funcname); funcname"`)

Comment: First I wanna get this working. Please help me in that

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, you should use `--` to separate the options from the command to execute:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do
    options_1+=("$tab" -- bash -c "${cmd_1[i]} ; bash" )
done
```

Also, you shouldn't put a space at the beginning of the value of `$tab`. Use

```
tab="--tab"
```

Comment: its doesnt seem to work. Now what happens is, in both terminal window only one tab gets opened which runs the commands of `cmd_1[1]` and `cmd_2[1]` respectively. The remaining tabs doesnt even open

Comment: I see, you're using multiple `-e` options to execute multiple commands in different tabs. The `--` syntax only allows a single command. I'm not sure that's possible with the new syntax, I'll research.

Comment: There are similar questions at [ubuntu.se], and I don't see any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
for i in 1 2 3; do
    gnome-terminal $tab -- bash -c "${cmd_1[i]} ; bash"
done
```

Comment: He wants them in separate tabs of the same terminal window. This will create separate windows.

Comment: @Barmar is right, I need multiple tabs under the same terminal window

Comment: If run from an existing `gnome-terminal` it opens new tabs (*at least that's how it worked for me*)

Comment: Yea, I have done that too, thats works pretty well. But I need those in one single window

Comment: It probably depends on `gnome-terminal` version

Answer (score 0):

I guess, what you need is something like this -

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd=("echo 1" "echo 2" "echo 3")

final=""

for c in "${cmd[@]}"; do
    final+="gnome-terminal --tab -- /bin/bash -c \"${c};bash\";"
done

gnome-terminal --window -- /bin/bash -c "$final"

exit 0
```

This will open a new window with 3 tabs, each running specified commands then kept open. Copy-pasting similar code, you can also open multiple windows each with any number of tabs and running any number of commands in them.